# Why is IEnumerable faster than IQueryable?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

### Introduction

I've been researching the difference between the two. I've decided to get my hands dirty and test them because I want to see the performance difference between the two (if any) and understand *why*.

I've created a simple console app. I'm using Entity Framework and SQL Server. I've created a model which points to a database table. The table has ~1000 records.

### The Tests

```
Dim _db As New SampleEntities
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
```

#### Test 1 - 966ms

```
Dim allMemos As IEnumerable(Of Memo) = _db.Memos
sw.Start()
allMemos.ToList()
sw.Stop()
```

#### Test 2 - 6ms

```
Dim iEnum As IEnumerable(Of Memo) = _db.Memos.AsEnumerable
sw.Restart()
iEnum.Where(Function(f) f.Active).ToList()
sw.Stop()
```

#### Test 3 - 186ms

```
Dim iQuer As IQueryable(Of Memo) = _db.Memos.AsQueryable
sw.Restart()
iQuer.Where(Function(f) f.Active).ToList()
sw.Stop()
```

### My Findings

Before I began, my research told me that in many cases IQueryable is faster because it is likely to optimise the query so that the filter (i.e. memo is `Active`) is performed by SQL and so very few results will be returned when `ToList()` is called.

However, my findings demonstrated the opposite. Why? I was sure that in my test IQueryable *would* be faster. I deliberately set it up to show this.

### "It's because you used iQuer As IQueryable(Of Memo)!"

I thought this too. I had heard that casting my objects as IQueryable might be bad because it has to convert from IEnumerable anyway. So I tried this:

```
Dim iQuer As IEnumerable(Of Memo) = _db.Memos.AsQueryable
```

And it **did** improve performance so that **Test 3** took 17ms instead of 186ms. But it's still slower than 6ms (Test 2).

What's going on here?

Comment: Boy, people are going to blah, blah, blah, about your "performance" testing. Be prepared.

Comment: That's ok. It's how I learn :D

Comment: @RowanFreeman I suggest you try this again with a few million rows. Performance testing with 1000 rows is not much of a performance test.

Comment: That's true, and partly answers my question which is "what am I doing wrong?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what _db.Memos returns but in test 2

```
Dim iEnum As IEnumerable(Of Memo) = _db.Memos.AsEnumerable
```

all the records may be loaded into memory there and then.

In test 3 the records are loaded when you call `ToList`:

```
  iQuer.Where(Function(f) f.Active).ToList()
```

You should do 2 things:

1. Move your stopwatch lines before the assignment and compare results then .
2. Setup a trace in your db to see where the code actually hits the database.